# TCP server and Browser as Web client in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, network-programming

Program:

```
//Server

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
void main()
{
    int fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    struct sockaddr_in sa,clientaddr;
    struct in_addr ip;

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&ip)!=1){
        perror("inet_pton");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sin_family=AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port=htons(5000);
    sa.sin_addr=ip;

    if(bind(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&sa,sizeof(sa))!=0){
        printf("Unable to Bind\n");
        perror("");
        exit(1);    
    }

    if(listen(fd,1024)!=0){
        printf("Unable to Listen \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int len=sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    int des;
    if((des=accept(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr,&len))<0){
        printf("Unable to accept\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Connection accepted....\n");

        char buf[1024];

        int r=recv(des,buf,1024,0);
        printf("Recived Data: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        write(1,buf,r);
        printf("\n");
        buf[0]='\0';
    }
}
```

The above program is the simple server program, which accept the client connection and accept data which is sent by client. I experiment it 
with telnet as shown below.

Server:

```
$ ./a.out 
Connection accepted....
Recived Data: ...Hai...
$
```

Client:

```
$ telnet localhost 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
...Hai...
Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

When using telnet, it is properly worked. But my requirement is instead of connecting with telnet, I have to connect with browser. I check
with browser as my client like "127.0.0.1:5000". And I expect any connection is established. But there is no reponse and the server process
didn't get any request. What is the problem behind this. Why the server didn't get request ?

Similar to telnet, browser also get the ip and port number and makes a TCP connection. But it doesn't work. Can any one explain why it is like
this ?

Comment: Are you not seeing "Connection accepted...." message when you use browser? Do use tcpdump to see whats happening on the wire

Answer (score 0):

Telnet will output whatever you send back to it, but browsers expect a full HTTP/1.1 response before rendering it.
It would be something like this (The \r\n are tricky):

```
header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" 
         + "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n" 
         + "\r\n";
```

Followed by whatever you want the browser to render.

That solves part of your problem, I don't know why you can't see the browser request in the server side (tipically a "GET / HTTP/1.1" or something like that), I would try changing the server not to exit after a single request (put in a while(1) loop and see what happens).

```
while(1){
    if((des=accept(fd,(struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr,&len))<0){
        printf("Unable to accept\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Connection accepted....\n");

        char buf[1024];

        int r=recv(des,buf,1024,0);
        printf("Recived Data: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        write(1,buf,r);
        printf("\n");
        buf[0]='\0';
    }
    close(des);
}
```

Comment: Still it doesn't work... Before sending header, it initiate the connection. Once the connection is established, then only it sends the header.